# Can Data table be used in Angular 2 to display a grid in component?

Tags: datagrid, angular

Which is the best way to display grid (pagination, Sorting, search & other basic functionalities) in an angular 2 web app? Kindly suggest!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what question to ask or not to ask and how to ask good questions.

Comment: its totally depends on your requirement and your comfort level what you want to use there are alot of tool available, please provide some code or explain your question bit more to clear what you actually want to do ?

Comment: You may want to check out PrimeNG DataTable. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: @CagatayCivici : Thank u so much. It suits my requirement.  :)